# Android Facebook SDK and authenticating on my server

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am trying to setup login on my app using facebook. Currently I have the SDK working fine, it authenticates and I can accession user information and then I start an Intent to my activity. (not sure if this is what I should be doing)

Now I am wondering what the workflow is for this is to authenticate with my RestAPI.

I can post the facebook_id to my server and add to my users database but I then read that I should be using the AccessToken, but how do I know if this is the correct AccessToken for that user?

What should be the flow here? Where should I be posting to the server and what should I be posting for every request in every Activity?

**Here is my code I currently have.**

```
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Session session, SessionState sessionState, Exception e) {
        if (sessionState.isOpened()) {
            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser graphUser, Response response) {
                    if (graphUser != null) {
                        Log.w(TAG, graphUser.getFirstName() + ' ' + graphUser.getId());
                        Log.w(TAG, session.getAccessToken() + ' ' + session.getExpirationDate());
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivityFragment.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        } else if (sessionState.isClosed()) {

        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the user ID as the unique identifier. The access token can change under many situations (updated permissions, user log in/out, etc), and should not be used to identify someone. The user ID will remain stable within your app.

You can send the access token along with the ID to your server, perhaps to make some FB requests from the server side, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: Should I be checking if the user_id is set on every Fragment? Also is it correct to have the intent I have above?

Comment: You should make a graph call to /me when your app starts (provided that you have a cached session), that way, as long as the user doesn't log out, you know you have the same user ID for the whole time.

Comment: Ok thanks. And is it correct to call an Intent to my mainActivity when a session is open?